# Error : ParseException line 2:0 missing EOF at 'LIKE' near ')'

Tags: hive, create-table, hiveddl

I would like to create externel table using like option.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test1 (rec string)
 LIKE 'EPCTR_201804'
 LOCATION '/hdfs/t1/tt1/PR/34/1xx/E1ERPSE/201801/PR/20180202-000758/*';
```

But this error was shown saying :

> FAILED: ParseException line 2:0 missing EOF at 'LIKE' near ')'

How can I resolve it please ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to give schema for new table. When you use `CREATE TABLE LIKE`, new table keeps the same schema as old one.

Use following:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test1 
 LIKE 'EPCTR_201804'
 LOCATION '/hdfs/t1/tt1/PR/34/1xx/E1ERPSE/201801/PR/20180202-000758/*';
```

Comment: Thanks but I get this error `ParseException line 1:7 cannot recognize input near 'CREATE' 'EXTERNEL' 'TABLE' in ddl statement`

Answer (score 0):

[Create Table Like](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-CreateTableLike) should be without columns specification, because LIKE means create table with the same exactly schema like the other table.

Also table location is a folder where the data files are being stored, there should be no `/*` at the end, like this:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test1 LIKE 'EPCTR_201804'
 LOCATION '/hdfs/t1/tt1/PR/34/1xx/E1ERPSE/201801/PR/20180202-000758';
```